# Make image as a link in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to make image as a link in Codeigniter but `<a>` tag is not working. I am trying to make image as a link but inside foreach loop `<a>` tag is not working.

Here is my code

```
 <?php if(count($trendpost)):?>
    <?php if(count($trendpost)<=3):?>
      <div class="row">
          <?php foreach($trendpost as $post): ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
              <a href=<?php echo site_url($post->url)?>> <img  class="imageborder trendimg" src=<?php echo site_url($post->link)?>></a>

                 <p><?= $post->news ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
       </div>
       <?php else: ?>
       <div class="row">
           <?php foreach($trendpost as $post) :?>
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                 <img class="imageborder trendimg" src=<?php echo site_url($post->link)?>>
                 <p><?= $post->news ?></p>
             </div>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
       <?php endif ?>
       <?php else: ?>
          <p> not found</p>
       <?php endif ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does *"is not working"* mean?  You have `<a>` tags but you can't click them or the `<a>` tags are missing?  Have you looked at the ***rendered*** HTML yet?

Comment: You have two loops... one with `<a>` tags and one without... it seems like you're just looking at the wrong loop.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this and please check again.

```
<?php if(count($trendpost)):?>
<?php if(count($trendpost)<=3):?>
  <div class="row">
      <?php foreach($trendpost as $post): ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
          <a href="<?php echo site_url($post->url)?>" style="display: block;"> <img  class="imageborder trendimg" src=<?php echo site_url($post->link)?>></a>

             <p><?= $post->news ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
   <?php else: ?>
   <div class="row">
       <?php foreach($trendpost as $post) :?>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
           <a href="<?php echo site_url($post->url)?>" style="display: block;">
             <img class="imageborder trendimg" src=<?php echo site_url($post->link)?>></a>
             <p><?= $post->news ?></p>
         </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
   <?php endif ?>
   <?php else: ?>
      <p> not found</p>
   <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php echo anchor('your Controller_name/link','<img src="your path"  /> ','class="btn btn-default btn-flat"')?>
```

instead of anchor Tag